# On the Weil representation of U(1) and U(3).

Tags: automorphic-forms, rt.representation-theory

Let $E/F$ quadratic extention number fields.
 Let $V$ be the $m$-dimension hermition vector space over $E$.
 Let $W$ be the $2n$-dimension skew hermitian vector space over $E$ and $Y_n + Y_n^*=W$ be the complete polarisation of it. (i.e $Y_n$ is $n$-dim maximal isotropic subspace of $W$)

Then, with some associated splitting characters, we can consider $\omega$, the Weil representation of $U(V) \times U(W)$ on the Schwartz space $S(Y_n^*  \otimes V)$.

And it is given explicitly by
$\omega(1,h) \phi (x)=\phi(h^{-1}x)$ for $h\in U(V)(\mathbb{A})$ &

$\omega(g,1) \phi (x)=\chi(det(g))|det(g)|^\frac{m}{2} \phi(g^{-1}x)$ for $g\in$ Levi factor of $U(W)(\mathbb{A})$

and so on... (here, $\chi$ is some Hecke character of $\mathbb{A_E}$)

I am considering Weil representation of $U(V)$ and $U(W)$ when $V$ is 3-dim hermition space and $W$ is 1-dim skew hermitian space over $E$. But in this case, since $W$ is 1-dimension, I cannot find its complete polarisation and so unable to find their Weil-represention as the above.

What is the proper model of Weil representation in this case and how can we realise it? (I mean, the explicit law of Weil representation as the above)

Comment: You can search Gelbart and Ragowski. They had several papers on U(3), where you could find a mix model.